# Images overlapping in HTML onload, but after refresh it back to normal in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website page built in html, however there was a weird thing happened. Whenever i browse that page in google chrome, the images displayed will be overlapping all times. However, this can be resolved when i do the page refresh or press F5. Can any experts please give your advice?

```
This is my section that having problem.
**HTML**
<section class="wrapper">
<section class="content portfolio medium-images">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row sub_content">
        <!--begin isotope -->
        <div class="col-lg-12 isotope">
           <!--begin portfolio_list -->
           <ul class="portfolio_list clearfix ">
              <!--begin List Item -->
              <li class="list_item col-md-3  col-lg-3 col-
                 sm-3">
                 <div class="recent-item">
                    <figure>
                       <img src="images/products
                          /Bearings.jpg" alt="" />
                    </figure>
                 </div>
                 <div class="text_option">
                    <h4>Bearings</h4>
                 </div>
              </li>
              <li class="list_item col-md-3  col-lg-3 col-
                 sm-3">
                 <div class="recent-item">
                    <figure>
                       <img src="images/products/Brakes.png" 
                          alt="" />
                    </figure>
                 </div>
                 <div class="text_option">
                    <h4>Brakes</h4>
                 </div>
              </li>
              <!--end List Item -->
           </ul>
           <!--end portfolio_list -->
        </div>
     </div>
     <!--./row-->
  </div>
  <!--./div-->
</section>
</section>
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML, CSS and JS which you have tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Actually i have tried on META REFRESH, and this before but it seems does not work.

Comment: META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">

Comment: Can you share your code html, css, for now I have shared my code you can refer.

Comment: Did you check the network tab? some file pending download, or wrong order of javascript files?

Comment: Start by temporarily renaming class names in the CSS file to see if, when they are not applied because you just renamed them, the problem persists. We are not interested in CSS rules that don't change the overlapping when not applied.

Answer (score -1):

Please refere this Demo to show two images without overlapping:

```
.mainRunner {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}

.img1 {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  float:left;
}

.img2 {
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
  position: relative;
  float:left;
}
<div class="mainRunner">
  <img class="img1" src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTG4mTuuZmylqn_qqviXFh5EPLD_DTsXMIjXT-4XJM0QPtJxw7lXw&t=1" />
  <img class="img2" src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTG4mTuuZmylqn_qqviXFh5EPLD_DTsXMIjXT-4XJM0QPtJxw7lXw&t=1" />
</div>
```